# Am I correctly showing a hydride shift on the alkyl halide?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

I did this quiz and I forgot the hydride shift.
[image]

With the hydride shift, would these be the right answer?
[image]

Comment: Huh? Check your images again--they both have 9 carbons, but you're adding an EtOH (2 carbons) to an 8-carbon molecule. I think once you make the numbers add up, you'll see the right answer.

Comment: Instead of the H, we should see a CH3 group.

Comment: Excellent! Now if you draw the molecules with CH3 instead of hydrogens, what happens?

Comment: We get the right amount of carbons? :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you solvolyze the starting bromide a secondary carbocation would be generated.  Since a secondary carbocation is not particularly stable, the molecule will explore other pathways such as hydrogen shift, alkyl shift, *etc*., in order to **produce a more stable carbocation**.  The figure below, explores these options for your starting bromide.  Realize that although I've drawn a discreet secondary carbocation that then undergoes rearrangement, in reality cation generation and alkyl or hydrogen shift may occur in a more or less concerted fashion.

[image]

In this case there are 3 options (actually there are 4 options, but the fourth one would produce a primary carbocation, so I left it out - can you find it?), a, b and c. Pathways a and c produce secondary carbocations; however pathway b, involving hydrogen shift, produces a more stable tertiary carbocation.  Capture of the tertiary carbocation from pathway c by solvent should produce the expected product.

Comment: Very clear. Thanks ron. I guess I just wrongly wrote H instead of CH3 in my attempt to correct my answer.